デスクトップ用の背景画像を適用させたい
mediaの中にデスクトップ用の背景画像を指定しているのですが、反映されません。
画像のpathは合っていました。
    <div class="sub-cover cover-news">
            <header class="page-header wrapper">
                <h1 class="align-center">
                    <a href="index.html"><img class="logo" src="images/logo.svg" alt="WBCカフェホーム"></a>
                </h1>
                <nav>
                    <ul class="main-nav font-english">
                        <li><a href="images/news.html">News</a></li>
                        <li><a href="images/menu.html">Menu</a></li>
                        <li><a href="images/contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </header>
            <h2 class="page-title font-english">News</h2>
     </div>

css
/*デスクトップ*/
@media (min-width:800px){
    /*見出し*/
    .page-title{
        font-size: 5rem;
    }
    .heading-large{
        font-size: 4rem;
    }
    .post-title{
        font-size: 2rem;
    }
    /*ヘッダー*/
    .page-header{
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        padding-top: 1.5rem;
    }
    .main-nav{
        font-size: 2rem;
    }

    /*ヘッダーカバー画像*/
    .sub-cover{
        height: 400px;
        margin-bottom: 6rem;
    }
    
    /*HOME*/
    .cover-home{
        background-image: url(../images/cover-home-l.webp);
    }

    .about{
        margin: 4rem auto 0;
    }
    
    /*News*/
    .cover-news{
        background-image: url(../images/cover-news-l.webp);
    }

    /*footer*/
    .page-footer{
        background-image: url(../images/footer-l.webp);
        padding-top: 12rem;
    }
    
    .info th{
        padding-left: 2.5rem;
    }
}

ディレクトリ構成


背景以外にfont-size等も指定されているようですが、そちらは意図通りに適用されたのでしょうか？ 「画像のpathは合っていました」の確認方法を記載してください。確認方法そのものが間違っている可能性もあります。

font-sizeは意図通りに適用されました。
画像のpathはcssファイルと同じ並びにある、imagesの中のcover-news-l.webpを指定しました。ファイルディレクトリ構成を確認しました。


font-sizeは意図通りに適用されました。 画像のpathはcssファイルと同じ並びにある、imagesの中のcover-news-l.webpを指定しました。ファイルディレクトリ構成を確認しました。

font-sizeは適用されるもののbackground-imageが適用されないという状況から、画像のpathが間違っていることが想定されます。確認したとのことですが、確認方法も間違っていると思われます。
background-imageに指定する<url>はHTMLファイルからの相対パスではなく、CSSファイルからの相対パスを指定する必要があります。

index.html
styles

style.css


images

cover-news-l.webp



というディレクトリ構成の場合は、../images/cover-news-l.webp と書きますが、

index.html
style.css
images

cover-news-l.webp



というディレクトリ構成の場合は、images/cover-news-l.webp と書くことになります。
この辺りは、質問文にCSSファイルの配置場所が言及されていないため分かりませんが、後者の状況ではないでしょうか？

なお、ブラウザーの開発者ツールのネットワークタブを参照することで、ブラウザーがHTML / CSSをどう解釈し、どのURLにアクセスしたかを確認することができます。background-imageは指定通りに解釈された上で、画像をダウンロードしようとして 404 Not Found になっているかと思います。
「確認方法が間違っている」というのはこのことを指します。

style.cssはcssのフォルダに入っており、cssフォルダはimagesと同じ列です。ネットワークタブにcover-news-l.webp自体が表示されません。


mediaの中にデスクトップ用の背景画像を指定しているのですが、反映されません。

コピペして試しましたが (画像は当方にあるものを使用)、幅 800px 前後で切り替わります。あなたが言う反映されないとはどういうことですか？
800px 未満

800px 以上


800px以上の画面でモバイル用の画像からデスクトップ用の画像に切り替わりません。画像は壊れていませんでした。pathはファイル構成を確認して,cssフォルダと同じ列にあるimagesの中のcover-news-l.webpを指定しました。

上の回答の画像の通り切り替わります。cover-news の background-image が幅 800px
以上になると表示されます。回答の画像を見たらわかりますよね。ダメなのは質問者さんんやり方の問題（何か間違っている・・・たぶんパス）です。

cssのmediaの部分をモバイル用の部分よりも先に記述していたのが問題でした。
この部分の前後を入れ替えると解決しました。皆様、ありがとうございました。
修正後のコード
@charset "UTF-8";

/* 共通部分
------------------------------- */
html {
    font-size: 100%;
}
body{
    font-family: "Hiragino Kaku Gothic ProN", "Hiragino Sans", "BIZ UDPGothic", sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.7;
    color: #432;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
img {
    max-width: 100%;
}

/* レイアウト */
.wrapper {
    max-width: 1120px;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0 1.5rem;
}
.align-center {
    text-align: center;
}

/* 見出し */
.font-english {
    font-family: 'Philosopher', sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
}
.page-title,
.heading-large,
.heading-medium {
    font-size: 3rem;
    text-align: center;
}
.page-title {
    margin-top: 2rem;
    line-height: 1.4;
}
.heading-large {
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

/* ボタン */
.btn {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    background-color: #0bd;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 8px;
    padding: .75rem 1.5rem;
    transition: .5s;
}
.btn:hover {
    background-color: #0090aa;
}

/* ヘッダー
------------------------------- */
.page-header {
    padding-top: .5rem;
}
.logo {
    width: 210px;
}
.main-nav {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    gap: 2.5rem;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    list-style: none;
}
.main-nav a {
    color: #432;
}
.main-nav a:hover {
    color: #0bd;
}

/* ヘッダーカバー画像
------------------------------- */
.cover {
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center bottom;
    height: 800px;
}
.sub-cover {
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center bottom;
    height: 528px;
    margin-bottom: 4rem;
}

/* HOME
------------------------------- */
.cover-home {
    background-image: url(../images/cover-home-s.webp);
}
.about {
    max-width: 736px;
    padding: 0 1.5rem;
    margin: 3rem auto 0;
}
.about p {
    margin-bottom: 3rem;
}

/* NEWS
------------------------------- */
.cover-news {
    background-image: url(../images/cover-news-s.webp);
}

/* 記事部分 */
.post {
    margin-bottom: 3rem;
}
.post-title {
    font-weight: normal;
    margin-bottom: 1.25rem;
}
.post-info {
    display: flex;
    gap: 1rem;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
}
.post-cat {
    display: flex;
    gap: .5rem;
    list-style: none;
}
.post-cat a {
    color: #432;
    background-color: #faf7f0;
    border-radius: 8px;
    font-size: .875rem;
    padding: .5rem .75rem;
}
.post-cat a:hover {
    background-color: #c9c2bc;
}
.post-date {
    font-size: .875rem;
}
.post-thumbnail {
    border-radius: 16px;
    margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
}
.post p {
    margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
    line-height: 2;
}

/* ↓ 追加 ↓ ------------------------------- */
/* サイドバー */
.side-menu {
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 4rem;
}
.side-menu li {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #c9c2bc;
}
.side-menu a {
    color: #432;
    display: block;
    padding: 1rem;
}
.side-menu a:hover {
    color: #0bd;
}
/* ↑ 追加 ↑ ------------------------------- */

/* フッター
------------------------------- */
.page-footer {
    background-image: url(../images/footer-s.webp);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    padding-top: 12rem;
}
.info {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 544px;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0 1.5rem;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
.info th,
.info td {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #c9c2bc;
}
.info th {
    text-align: left;
    font-weight: normal;
    padding: 1rem;
}
.info td {
    padding: 1rem 0;
}
.copyright {
    background-color: #432;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 2rem 0;
    margin-top: 6rem;
    color: #fff;
}

/* デスクトップ版
------------------------------- */
@media (min-width: 800px) {
    /* 見出し */
    .page-title {
        font-size: 5rem;
    }
    .heading-large {
        font-size: 4rem;
    }
    .post-title {
        font-size: 2rem;
    }

    /* ヘッダー */
    .page-header {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        padding-top: 1.5rem;
    }
    .main-nav {
        font-size: 2rem;
    }

    /* ヘッダーカバー画像 */
    .sub-cover {
        height: 400px;
        margin-bottom: 6rem;
    }

    /* HOME */
    .cover-home {
        background-image: url(../images/cover-home-l.webp);
    }
    .about {
        margin: 4rem auto 0;
    }

/* ↓ 追加 ↓ ------------------------------- */
    /* NEWS */
    .cover-news {
        background-image: url(../images/cover-news-l.webp);
    }
/* ↑ 追加 ↑ ------------------------------- */

    /* フッター */
    .page-footer {
        background-image: url(../images/footer-l.webp);
        padding-top: 12rem;
    }
    .info th {
        padding-left: 2.5rem;
    }
}


フォントは適用されたが画像がダメだったという話のはずですが、それが「前後を入れ替えると解決」とどうつながるのでしょう？

自分もよくわかりませんが、これは入門書に沿って進めています。
答えのコードと比較して、デスクトップとモバイルの前後と入れ替えると
解決しました。

入れ替える過程で、コピーとペーストを使用した場面もあったのでその際に、他の見落としてるミスも解決されているのかもしれませんね。

一応、変更後のコードも追加しておきますね

上の私の回答にも書きましたが、あなたの質問にあったコードをそのままコピペして試した結果 (画像は当方にあるものを使用)、幅 800px 前後で切り替わります。画像は存在してパスも合っている、でもそうならないということですが、そうであれば実際と違うコードを質問にアップしたということではないのですか？
